# How to show a title for image when I hover over it in JavaFx

Tags: image, javafx, title

I am doing a project via JavaFx and I have an image and I want to display some information about that image when I hover above it (like the title tag in html).

Any idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Tooltip (`Tooltip.install()`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-).

```
Tooltip.install(myImageView, new Tooltip("This is my image."));
```

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you're looking for is implemented in [the `Tooltip` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html) and you can add one to a `ImageView` using `Tooltip.install`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("stackoverflow logo");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a");
    imageView.setPickOnBounds(true);
    Tooltip.install(imageView, tooltip);

    StackPane root = new StackPane(imageView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

You can easily write a utility class that allows you to install the `Tooltip` from an fxml file:

```
package fxml;

import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;

public final class TooltipUtil {

    private TooltipUtil() {}

    public static void setTooltip(Node node, Tooltip tooltip) {
        Tooltip.install(node, tooltip);
    }

    // only here for the FXMLLoader
    @Deprecated
    public static Tooltip getTooltip(Node node) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import fxml.TooltipUtil?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <ImageView pickOnBounds="true" >
            <image>
                <Image url="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a"/>
            </image>
            <TooltipUtil.tooltip>
                <Tooltip text="stackoverflow logo" />
            </TooltipUtil.tooltip>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: If i have defined my image in fxml which should I choose to call the above function once I hover over the image ?

Comment: @DanialKosarifa Give the ImageView an `id` (e.g. myImageView). Then in your controller, add `@FXML private ImageView myImageView;`. Thereafter, you can add the tooltip in your controller.

Comment: @Danial Added some code demonstrating how to add the tooltip from the fxml itself...